# ui-grid-cell-contents CSS Alignment

Tags: css, angular-ui

I am trying to align .ui-grid-cell-contents only first column. not all the columns.

```
.ui-grid-cell-contents:first-child {
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

but this code is not working properly. could you please help me out?

Comment: Please share your code or make a demo.

Comment: Try to target them using parent class. for example.  .parent > .ui-grid-cell-contents:first-child {  margin-left:20px;}

Comment: Thanks Sahil. Its working fine.